# ignore "default" functions in c

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with a "re-made" function that I've built in C.

I've rebuilt strlen and strncat from the string.h library (for educational purposes) and it does compile, but immediately crashes. In addition, there's a warning saying that strncat already exists, even though I did not include the  header file.

And yes, I've used the same name.

How can this be? How can I fix this?

**tl;dr** rebuilt a c function from , and even though I didn't include it, it still thinks it already exists

Comment: There's no way we can know what you did wrong if you don't show us your code.  Please update your question with a [mcve].  Also, don't name your functions the same as library functions.  Give them a different name.

Comment: The command you're using to compile/link would also be relevant here.

Comment: The C library is linked into your executable by default (removing that is possible but then you have to re-implement a bunch of stuff). The linked question has better alternatives.

Comment: Thank you! I'll just change the name.